# filtro de búsqueda mediante <select>

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer el típico filtro de búsqueda que ordena los resultados con las siguientes opciones.

```
<select name="orden">                          
    <option value="1">Hora: publicación más reciente</option>
    <option value="2">Precio: más bajo primero</option>
    <option value="3">Precio: más alto primero</option>
    <option value="4">Distancia: más cercano primero</option>
    <option value="5">Relevancia</option>
    <option value="6">Urgentes</option>
</select>
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer, y que no consigo, es que al cambiar una opción automáticamente se re-ordene la búsqueda si tener que pulsar un `<input type="submit">`

Comment: Cómo estás intentando hacerlo? Pon el código con los avances que hayas hecho para orientarte

Comment: _se re-ordene la búsqueda_ ¿qué **búsqueda**?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. lee cómo crear una buena pregunta. Debes editar tu pregunta con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Debes agregar mas código. ¿qué usaste para lograr la funcionalidad que mencionas? edita tu pregunta.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos a suponer esta estructura mínima:

```
 <form action="POST" id="formOrden">
    <select id="orden" name="orden">                          
        <option value="1">Hora: publicación más reciente</option>
        <option value="2">Precio: más bajo primero</option>
        <option value="3">Precio: más alto primero</option>
        <option value="4">Distancia: más cercano primero</option>
        <option value="5">Relevancia</option>
        <option value="6">Urgentes</option>
   </select>
 </form>
```

Tendríamos dos formas de hacerlo. Con "vanilla javascript" o "javascript puro":

```
document.getElementById('orden').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('formOrden').submit();
});
```

Con jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').on('change', '#orden', function(){
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Ambas opciones son válidas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Muriano, era justo esto lo que buscaba. Un saludo